# What is the difference between 'share to' and 'share with'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Should I use 'share with' or 'share to' when I want to share a great page I've seen on a social networking site with a friend?

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question?

Comment: It's not that there's a "difference";  the idiomatic construction is "share {something} with {someone}" or "share with {someone} something {relative clause}", e.g. "I'd like to share with you something I heard on the radio last night".

Answer (score 1):

When you ***share*** something, the standard preposition before the "beneficiaries" is...

> 1: *I shared the story **with** my family*
> 2: *I shared the story **with** my friends on Facebook*

...but it's possible to specify just the *location* where you put the shared material, in which case we use a different preposition...

> 3: [*I shared the story **to** Facebook*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22shared%20it%20to%20facebook%22)
> 4:  [*I shared the story **on** Facebook*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22shared%20it%20on%20facebook%22)

Some people might not like one or the other (or both!) of those prepositions, but I have no problem with either. Nor do I have any particularly strong preference between them - but apparently [*most* people prefer ***on*** there.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shared%20it%20on%20Facebook%2Cshared%20it%20to%20Facebook&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: Facebook "sharing" (and similar) is actually a new meaning of the word, I think you'd agree, "to publish or 'post' content to social media on the internet".  In pre-internet times we might have said "I shared my pet's disappearance with the neighborhood" but we would not have said "I shared my pet's disappearance to the bulletin board at the library."

Comment: Facebook is just a more accessible referent for people today. 50 years ago you could have shared feelings / information / secrets on / to the school magazine, or public toilet walls.

Comment: You actually said that in the UK in pre-internet times?   e.g.  *Someone has shared an anatomically correct drawing to the toilet wall* or  *A funny story has been shared by Anonymous to the school magazine*?  We never said **share to** in AmE until the advent of internet social media.

Comment: @TimR: Maybe my technical background makes me atypical, but I was certainly sharing stuff ***on the network*** decades before Facebook existed, and I don't see any syntactic difference between magazines, walls, facebook, and networks in this context. They're all just places where you can put stuff for others to access.

Comment: But **on** isn't **to**.

Comment: @TimR: *Frame challenge!* Your first comment seems to be claiming that *[sharing] content **to** social media **on** the internet* is a "new" preposition usage. I can't really see any difference between that and *sharing content **to** the Internet **on** Facebook*. And like I said, I personally don't attach much significance to the exact choice of such prepositions. I think you're just quibbling for the sake of it.

Comment: I'm not "quibbling" about anything. I am asking about **sharing to {somewhere}**, and whether that locution was used in the UK, pre-internet.  You seemed to suggest as much in an earlier comment. In AmE, that combo didn't exist until internet social media.

Comment: Well, if you think you speak for all Americans, I won't argue. But I simply don't believe no Americans would have seen things the same way I do *and did*.

Comment: I asked you a simple direct question. Did Brits say "share {something} **to** {somewhere}"  before internet social media?  No need for  quasi *ad hominem* remarks like me "speaking for" all Americans.

Answer (score 1):

I heard "share (something) to (someone)" for the first time earlier today.  It sounds horrible to me, but I imagine that it makes sense if you think of it as "send (something) to (someone) by means of the *share* function."

I'm sure we haven't seen the last of "share to."

Comment: [Cold War International History Project Bulletin, 1992](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+will+also+try+to+put+into+context+mr%22) - *We will also try to put into context Mr. Leitenberg's presentation of the observations **shared to him** during a talk in 1980 with a former Polish party and government official...*